# Does the Anti-Up, Anti-Strange, Anti-Strange Quark combination form a Baryon?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, baryons

I was using this applet:
http://www.lon-capa.org/~mmp/applist/q/q.htm
And I saw that the up, strange, strange quark combination formed this Baryon:

[image]

But the anti-up, anti-strange, anti-strange combination didn't form anything. So is that a fault of the applet or is there an actual reason? What would the reason be?

Comment: The applet only shows the possible Baryons(three quark bound state). anti-up, anti-strange, anti-strange is an Anti-baryon of the corresponding Xi baryon.

Comment: @Hubble07 the app does show anti baryons such as the anti-proton and anti-neutron, but doesn't show anti-Xi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be an anti-Xi baryon.

Production of Xi / anti-Xi pairs in discussed in [Branching Fraction Measurements of psi(2S) Decay to Baryon-Antibaryon Final States](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0505057).

So yes it does form something and it is a fault of the applet.

Comment: technically the applet is right it is only designed to show particle not anti-particle

Comment: @Hubble07 it shows other anti-baryons and has icons to click to select antiquarks